# Postgresql - running subquery doesn't show results for an user

Tags: postgresql, roles

i have this user in the database, this user only needs read permissions, here the permissions that has right now:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema TO "user";
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO "user";
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA myschema to "user";
```

If the runs this query didn't show results, but if I use an admin-user show me results:

```
SELECT "tableA"."tableA_id", "tableA"."first_name", "tableA"."last_name", "brands"."brand_id" AS "brands.brand_id",
"brands->tableB"."door_id" AS "brands.tableB.door_id", "brands->tableB"."agent_id" AS "brands.tableB.agent_id",
"brands->tableB"."tableA_id" AS "brands.tableB.tableA_id", "brands->tableB"."brand_id" AS "brands.tableB.brand_id",
"brands->tableB"."relationship_type" AS "brands.tableB.relationship_type", "agents"."agent_id" AS "agents.agent_id", 
"agents"."relationship_type" AS "agents.relationship_type" 
FROM "myschema"."tableA" AS "tableA" 
INNER JOIN ( "myschema"."tableB" AS "brands->tableB" INNER JOIN "myschema"."brand" AS "brands" ON "brands"."brand_id" = "brands->tableB"."brand_id") ON "tableA"."tableA_id" = "brands->tableB"."tableA_id" AND "brands"."brand_id" = 1 
INNER JOIN "myschema"."tableB" AS "agents" ON "tableA"."tableA_id" = "agents"."tableA_id" AND "agents"."relationship_type" = 'Employee' 
WHERE "tableA"."active" = true ORDER BY "tableA"."first_name" ASC;
```

Any idea which privileges are need it to check this data?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing permissions don't influence the query result, they cause "permission denied" errors. The exceptions I know are

- queries on `information_schema` views, which only show objects on which you have permissions
- row-level security

If anything, your question suggests that row-level security is at play here.

If you need a more detailed answer, you have to add details to the question.